# Handling Activities in Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on a network quiz and I'm running into the problem of handling an activity from a thread. This is my code for the `Client`, that (successfully) connects to a server:

```
public class Client extends Thread {
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Socket socket;

    private DataInputStream dataIn;
    private DataOutputStream dataOut;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public Client(String host, int port, MainActivity activity) {

            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.activity = activity;

//          At this point of the code, it works just great:
            activity.setQuestion("Question", "A", "B", "C", "D", 1);


            this.start();
    }

    private void processMessage( String msg ) {
        try {
            dataOut.writeUTF(msg);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    void handleMessage(String msg) {
        if (msg.equals("changeQuestion")) {

//          This does not work:
            activity.setQuestion("Question", "A", "B", "C", "D", 1);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket( host, port );
            dataIn = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
            dataOut = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

            while (true) {
                String msg = dataIn.readUTF();
                handleMessage(msg);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   


    }

}
```

The `setQuestion(...)` method is called in the `MainActivity`, where the questions' and the answer buttons' captions are set to strings.
As my comments tell you, it does work, before the thread is started, but once the thread is started, it crashes.

This is my `setQuestion(...)` method, which lies in the `MainActivity`:

```
public void setQuestion(String Q, String A, String B, String C, String D, int correctAnswer) {

    TextView tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    tvQuestion.setText("");

    Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerA);
    Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerB);
    Button btnC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerC);
    Button btnD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswerD);

    tvQuestion.setText(Q);
    btnA.setText(A);
    btnB.setText(B);
    btnC.setText(C);
    btnD.setText(D);

    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
```

Comment: you cannot update ui from a `thread`

Comment: Thank you. I'll find another solution, then.

Comment: you can use `runOnUiThread` which is a method of activity class. check my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating ui from thread is not possible. `setQuestion` is called from the thread and you set text to buttons in setQuestion.

Check the topic under threads @

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

You can use a `Handler` or `Asynctask` or `runOnUiThread`

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    activity.setQuestion("Question", "A", "B", "C", "D", 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: That was easy! Thank you, just enough for what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Your handleMessage() is being called from the new Thread, not the main UI thread. Consider using AsyncTask for things such as this. That is the clean way.

Comment: That I know. I however thought, I could update the UI from inside a thread, which seems to be illegal. Thank you, though.

Comment: yes, don't do it - if it seems to work it might glitch out every once in awhile